# bootstrap Modal 2.3.2 automatically loads on IE-11

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using IE-11 and I have a modal that automatically loads inside my form. It does not respect the the onClick(). Also, the data-toggle does not work. It also loads automatically.

```
 <form ...>
        <div id="manage" class="tab-pane">
        <div id="media_action_div">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg media_action_buttons" id="tag_media" disabled="disabled" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#tag_media_modal">Tag</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger media_action_buttons" id="delete_media" disabled="disabled">Delete</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success media_action_buttons" id="activate_media" disabled="disabled">Activate</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning media_action_buttons" id="deactivate_media" disabled="disabled">Deactivate</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default media_action_buttons" id="download_media" disabled="disabled">Download</button>
        </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

Here's my modal:

```
<!-- Modal HTML -->
<div id="media_delete_confirmation" class="modal">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Confirmation</h4>
            </div>

                <div class="modal-body">
                    <p>What would you like to do?</p>
                    <p class="text-warning"><small>"Delete" will remove the media.</small></p>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary media_delete_footer" data-dismiss="modal">Keep</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default media_delete_footer" id="modal_delete" data-dismiss="modal">Delete</button>
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's my simple JS:

```
$("#delete_media").click(function(){
   $("#media_delete_confirmation").modal('show');
});
```

Here's my "Tag" button:

```
<!-- Modal HTML -->
<div id="tag_media_modal" class="modal">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Tag</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="container">
                    <?php
                        echo $PARSER->search(array(
                            'search' => $PARSER->student,
                            'actions' => '<button name="action" value="Upload" class="btn">Search</button>'
                        ));
                    ?>
                </div>
                <?php echo $PARSER->form_upload->Html(); ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Make sure if the bootstrap or its plugins are loaded once in the page context, it might lead to such anomalies.

Comment: what do you mean by "automatically loads"? inorder to show onclick you need to first hide the modal.

Comment: when I open the page, it opens right away. It should not. it should only open the modal when I clicked on the buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#media_delete_confirmation").hide();
  $("#delete_media").click(function(){
 $("#media_delete_confirmation").show();
 });
})
```